# windows phone deserialization json

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, json-deserialization

I have a weird issue. so I am making a few calls in my app to a webservice, which replies with data. However I am using a token based login system, so the first time the user enters the app I get a token from the webservice to login for that specific user and that token returns only that users details.

The problem I am having is when the user changes I need to make the calls again, to get the new user's details, but using visual studio's breakpoint debugging, it shows the new user's token making the call however the problem is when the json is getting deserialized, it is as if it still reads the old data and deserializes that, when I exit my app with the new user it works fine, so its as if it is reading cached values, but I have no idea how to clear it? I am sure the new calls are being made and the problem lies with the deserializing, but I have tried clearing the values before deserializing them again, however nothing works. am I missing something with the json deserializer, how van I clear its cached values?

here I make the call and set it not to cache so it makes a new call everytime:

```
  client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl] = "no-cache";
  var token_details = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
```

and here I deserialize the result, it is at this section the old data gets shown, so the raw json being shown inside "token_details" is correct, only once I deserialize the token_details, it shows the wrong data.

deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(token_details);

and the class I am deserializing into is a simple class nothing special happening here, I have even tried making the constructor so that it clears the values each time it gets called.

```
 public class test
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string birthday{ get; set; }
    public string errorDes{ get; set; }


    public test()
    {
        status = "";
        name= "";
        birthday= "";
        errorDes= "";
      }
}
```

uri's before making the calls:

{https://whatever.co.za/token/?code=BEBCg==&id=WP7&junk=121edcd5-ad4d-4185-bef0-22a4d27f2d0c} - old call

"UBCg==" - old reply

{https://whatever.co.za/token/?code=ABCg==&id=WP7&junk=56cc2285-a5b8-401e-be21-fec8259de6dd} - new call

"UBCg==" - new response which is the same response as old call

as you can see i did attach a new GUID everytime i make the call, but then the new uri is read before making the downloadstringtaskasync method call, but it returns with the old data

- "&junk=" + Guid.NewGuid());

Comment: I have tried other webservice calls, such as the httpwebrequest one instead of webclient, however I am getting the same result. something in the deserialize going wrong. thanx for any help

Comment: are you completely sure, that token_details before desrialization is correct, that it contains new token data? it is very likely that it doesn't. otherwise, post the code from creating the request to deserializing it.

Comment: thank you, I double checked and you were correct: I have narrowed it down now, the part where I do downloadstringtaskasync - the problem is happening in this method, the new user's URI is displayed in the brackets however immediately after the downloadstringtaskasync is done it is as if it is downloading the cached values. but everytime I do that part of the code I create a new instance of client, as well I clear everything and also I added the no-cache header when making the call. am I still missing something?

Comment: oyes also on the uri that I am making a call to, I add a random value EVERYTIME I make the call, so I make sure it is a "fresh" uri being called

Comment: i had a problem with caching and setting CacheControl to no-cache didn't help, but adding stamp to uri *did*. Could you post the code for uri creation?

Comment: i am not doing anything special when building the uri, just doing Uri uri = new Uri(); but i have updated the post to show you how the uris look when making the call

Comment: Do you use Newtonsoft json library? Maybe you should use "JsonProperty" attributes in your class.

Comment: yes I use the newtonsoft library, what do you mean, do I need to attach the class with jsonProperties? I will try this, but what will it do differently, like how will this fix it? (just asking)

Comment: as far as i can tell, you're doing everything right. those are different uris, so no caching is possible. perhaps you're not passing the correct uri to DownloadStringTaskAsync? perhaps the server logic is different then you expect and it is a valid response (bug on server side?)?